# Projecting lat/long to pixels with float accuracy instead of int

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using mapbox.js to create a voronoi map. However, I'm having issues with the accuracy of my projections from the latitude/longitude to the pixels on my screen as the accuracy is only int instead of float. This causes the points to change slightly when zooming in/out, causing the overall voronoi map to change!

**Edit:** I've updated the code to also include the code that generates the voronoi. You can see that the voronoi code uses the pixels, which is thus problematic as the accuracy can be problematic.

```
var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .x(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return d.y;
    });

filteredPoints.forEach(function (d) {
    var latlng = new L.LatLng(d.latitude, d.longitude);
    var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(latlng);
    d.x = point.x;
    d.y = point.y;
}

voronoi(filteredPoints).forEach(function (d) {
            d.point.cell = d;
});
```

Comment: Accuracy of what?  The screen pixel x,y?  You can't have a pixel at a fractional offset (like 0.3), thus the point will most likely be whole numbers.

Comment: I've tried to update my original post. Does it make more sense now? I can see that I can't have pixels with a fractional value, but I'd really like a transformation from latitude/longitude that converts into a fractional value.

Comment: [Read the Leaflet source](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/024e01ec3ade1cd08f5163ea58c90db04129a3d0/src/map/Map.js#L389-L392) and write the same thing, except without the call to `round()`

Comment: I've had a lot of issues previously with copying code from D3, which used restricted methods, so I had completely forgotten that one could simply do that. Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @tmcw, do you want to make a answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Leaflet source and write the same thing, except without the call to round()